# alternative/replacement for discrete-panel in Grafana v8

Tags: grafana, dashboard

How to implement horizontal graph in Grafana v8 ?

The former [Discrete](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/natel-discrete-panel/) panel ([by NatelEnergy](https://github.com/NatelEnergy/grafana-discrete-panel)) is not signed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Grafana [State timeline](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/state-timeline/) visualization introduced in Grafana [v8.0](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/whatsnew/whats-new-in-v8-0/).

**There are some examples on ▶▶ [play.grafana.org](https://play.grafana.org/d/qD-rVv6Mz/6-state-timeline-and-status-history?orgId=1)**

[image]